# The diophantine equation $ m = x^2 + 7y^2 $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I found this theorem.

> A prime number $m \ne 7$ can be written as $x^2 + 7y^2$ for $x,y$ integers
> iff $m$ is one of these residues modulo $28$
> $1, 9, 11, 15, 23, 25$

It is stated in the first pages of this book.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Primes-Form-ny2-Multiplication-Mathematics/dp/1118390180/

So far so good. But what does that imply for composite numbers $m$? And how does it imply it?
Is there some simple statement of this kind for composite numbers $m$?

I read some theory about all this but it all talks only about primes.
How do we make the leap to composites from there?

I think it's related to this
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity
but I cannot quite make the leap to composites.

Is the leap to composites more complicated than just knowing this theorem and this identity?

E.g. is this following true: if we take $m$ and divide it by its largest divisor $M^2$, then what's left must be factored only into primes of the above mentioned residues?! I thought this is true but seems it's not. I am checking it computationally and it seems to me it is false.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3699659/?  (Frankly, I am not sure why the theorem uses modulo $28$, when modulo $14$ is sufficient.)

Comment: Are $p$ and $m$ (and the $n$ in the title) related in some way?

Comment: They should all be $m$ sorry. @Batominovski I am not sure I will understand the answer there but I will try. I am asking if there's some easy formulation for composite numbers $m$.

Comment: The forward direction (that $m$ has such representations implies that $m$ belongs to certain classes modulo $14$ or $28$) is not difficult.  Quadratic reciprocity finishes that quickly.  The other direction is the part I am not sure whether there exists an elementary argument.

Comment: $7 = 0^2 + 7 \cdot 1^2$ and does not have one of those residues mod $28$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Right, the theorem is just for primes other than 7.

Comment: By the way, I covered in my answer in the linked thread both the prime and composite cases.

Comment: @Batominovski But that other thread is about some special form of $n$ only. No?

Comment: My answer in that link discusses all cases.  Certain values of $n$ do not admit such representations.  See everything after the paragraph starting with "In general, let $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$."

Comment: $32 = 5^2+7\cdot 1^2$, but $32 = 28\cdot 1 +2^2$.

Answer (score 2):

A number $m$ that you are able to factor: there is an integer expression $m = x^2 + 7 y^2$  if and only if

(I) the exponent of the prime $2$ is not one: either that exponent is $0$ or it is at least 2, AND

(II) the exponent of any prime $q \equiv 3,5,6 \pmod 7$ is EVEN

the exponent of $7$ and the exponents of primes $o \equiv 1,2,4 \pmod 7$ are not restricted.

Answer (score 2):

An addendum to Will Jagy's answer:

- $x^2+7y^2$ is the only reduced binary quadratic form of discriminant $-28$, hence any odd prime $p$ such that $-7$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$ can be represented by such a form; by quadratic reciprocity odd primes of the form $7k+1,7k+2,7k+4$ are *good* primes and primes of the form $7k+3,7k+5,7k+6$ are *bad* primes
- $x^2+7y^2$ does not represent $2$ but it represents $4,8,16,32,\ldots$
- the norm on $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-7}]$ gives us Lagrange identity $(x^2+7y^2)(X^2+7Y^2)=(xX+7yY)^2+7(xY-yX)^2$
- by Fermat's descent, if an odd squarefree number $m$ can be represented as $x^2+7y^2$ then all its divisors can be represented by such a form.

Summarizing, since $7$ is a [Heegner number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number) we have a minor variation on the problem of understanding which numbers can be represented as a sum of two squares.